# issue with multi-person tracking with PoseNet using JavaScript & TensorFlow

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

We are using an issue with multi-person tracking with the PoseNet library for Javascript.   We are seeing the data getting associated with the wrong person sometimes.

person 1

- tracking data

person 2

- tracking data

some time later:

person 1

- tracking data of person 2

person 2

- tracking data of person 1

We can add some code in Javascript to check the validity of the data.  Is this the way multi-person tracking works in PoseNet or a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posenet doesn't track people that way. It just looks for people and creates an array in somewhat random order. In other words, it starts over with every frame, with no knowledge of the previous frames. You would have to write an algorithm of your own.

My suggestion would be to look at the points in the face in each frame and compare them to the points from the previous frame. A naive approach would be to simply find the face in the previous frame that is closest to the face in the current frame. If you needed to do this in a more sophisticated way, you would need do blob tracking where you are actually looking at the colors/composition of each person and making sure they match across frames.

Comment: That is more or less what we ended up doing in JavaScript.  It is adequate for now.  We are also looking to use ML with sensor data from hardware sensors from Intel & Orbecc.  There are plans to make the code and some components open source.

Comment: Do you know how to run 2 tensorflow.js models concurrently in a react app?